# Sentence Transformation

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

I want to transform

> *Father was too angry with us to speak.*

to

> *Father was so ______*

My answers to the questions are:

1. Father was so angry with us (that) he couldn't speak.
2. Father was so angry with us (that) he wouldn't speak (to us).
3. Father was so angry with us (that) he didn't speak (to us).

Which one is correct? If all of these are acceptable, which is the best?

Comment: There is some semantic difference between couldn't and wouldn't.

Comment: *And* there's a semantic difference / nuance between both of those and *didn't*. But the question is meaningless, since *Father was too angry with us to speak* could apply to all three "expansions".

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence "as is"

> Father was too angry with us to speak.

means "Father was unable to speak because he was too angry with us to do so".

The pattern  `too {X} to {do something}` means that doing {something} is impossible because of the degree of {X}.

If you paraphrase with "so {x} that...", the *that*-clause must express impossibility.

> Father was so angry with us that he *could not* speak.

Comment: Disagree. That is the most likely, but it could be any of them.

Comment: Father was too angry with us to speak [full stop].  I don't think that means father was unwilling to speak (would not speak) or that father was expressing his anger by not speaking (would not speak) but that father was incapable of speech because of the extent of his anger.

Comment: @TRomano That's a likely reading but it isn't the only one.

Comment: @Araucaria: I would be happy to have the alternative readings explained to me.  For me the sentence is unambiguously a statement of *incapability* or *impossibility*: "The limo was too long to fit in the parking spot."  Father found it impossible to speak, he was so angry with us. Father was so angry with us that he found it impossible to speak.

Comment: Well, for example, I'm to angry to speak to them can just mean that I'm too angry with them to bother to speak to them or I'm too angry to want to speak to them. It doesn't have to mean that I'm so angry that it's impossible for me to speak to to them.

Comment: You're adding "to them" to the end of the sentence.  Big diff. Hence my [full stop] in the comment above and the caveat "as is" in the answer.

Comment: @TRomano I agree that the absence of *to them* makes your reading much more salient. But I still think depending on the context that he could just be to angry to bother to speak or want to speak or too feel like speaking. I don't think impossibility is encoded into the literal meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria: I think incapability is all that's encoded in the sentence. Anything beyond that (e.g. not wanting to *bother* to speak) requires something more, a prepositional phrase or an adverb, something to color the stark incapability/impossibility with nuance.